# Getting OAuth verifier value as null

Tags: oauth

I am trying to get access token for which I need OAuth verifier. I am using TokenSecretVerifierHolder class to get token, token secret and verifier but I am only getting the value of token, token secret, however the verifier value is coming aa null. Here is my code.

```
public TokenSecretVerifierHolder getRequestToken() {
        try {
            OAuthAccessor accessor = getAccessor();
            OAuthClient oAuthClient = new OAuthClient(new HttpClient4());
            List<OAuth.Parameter> callBack;
            if ((this.callback == null) || ("".equals(this.callback))) {
                callBack = Collections.emptyList();
            } else {
                callBack = ImmutableList.of(new OAuth.Parameter("oauth_callback", this.callback));
            }
            OAuthMessage message = oAuthClient.getRequestTokenResponse(accessor, "POST", callBack);
            TokenSecretVerifierHolder tokenSecretVerifier = new TokenSecretVerifierHolder();
            tokenSecretVerifier.token = accessor.requestToken;
            tokenSecretVerifier.secret = accessor.tokenSecret;
            tokenSecretVerifier.verifier = message.getParameter("oauth_verifier");
            return tokenSecretVerifier;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to obtain request token", e);
        }
    }

private String getAccessToken() {

    AtlassianOAuthClientRequest jiraoAuthClient = getJiraOAuthClient();
    TokenSecretVerifierHolder requestToken = jiraoAuthClient.getRequestToken();
    String authorizeUrl = jiraoAuthClient.getAuthorizeUrlForToken(requestToken.token);

    String token = requestToken.token;
    String tokenSecret = requestToken.secret;
    String verifier = requestToken.verifier;

    String accessToken = jiraoAuthClient.swapRequestTokenForAccessToken(token, tokenSecret, verifier);
    String verifier = requestToken.verifier;
    System.out.println("Access token is : " + accessToken);
    return accessToken;
}
```

After retreiving the value of token, token secret and verifier I am passing it to get the access token value. What I want is that after I acknowledge the authorizeUrl it should return me the value of Oauth verifier. In my case its returning as null.

Answer (score 0):

The required value of verifier is returned to you during HTTP redirect to your callback URL - the redirect happens with URL like `https://consumer.url/?oauth_token=TOKEN&oauth_verifier=VERIFIER`, so value of `oauth_verifier` parameter is what you need.